# How do I convert a time attribute of a time series in to Date format in R?

Tags: r

I have a time attribute of a time series:

```
time(ts(1:20, start = c(2014, 1), frequency = 12))
```

I want to convert this in to a series of dates (in Date format).

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How about `as.Date(time(...`

Comment: it's not working. I though that was supposed to work. I don't know why. Will it have to do with the fact that I have tseries installed?

Comment: Based on the example provided, it worked for me. `t1 <- ts(1:20, start = c(2014, 1), frequency = 12); head(as.Date(time(t1)))
#[1] "2014-01-01" "2014-02-01" "2014-03-01" "2014-04-01" "2014-05-01"
[6] "2014-06-01"` `ts` is a `base R` function.  I am using `R 3.2.0`

Comment: I loaded the `tseries` package, but it didn't have any effect.  Could you try this on a fresh R session without loading any package

Comment: I restarted R (3.1.3) and this is the message I get: as.Date(time(ts(1:20, start = c(2014, 1), frequency = 12)))
Error in as.Date.default(time(ts(1:20, start = c(2014, 1), frequency = 12))) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time(ts(1:20, start = c(2014, 1), frequency = 12))' to class “Date”

Comment: I'm using a 64 bit running on windows.

Comment: I am using `linux mint 17`. Not sure if it is OS related.

Comment: updated to 3.2 but still unsuccessful...

Answer (score 0):

It is not an OS error, the error occurs because there is no `as.Date.ts` method in your session, whereas there is in @Akrun's session:

This is when I start my R session:

```
> t1 <- ts(1:20, start = c(2014, 1), frequency = 12); head(as.Date(time(t1)))
Error in as.Date.default(time(t1)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time(t1)' to class “Date”
```

and:

```
> methods('as.Date')
[1] as.Date.character as.Date.date      as.Date.dates     as.Date.default   as.Date.factor    as.Date.numeric   as.Date.POSIXct   as.Date.POSIXlt
```

However, if you load the `xts` package then a `as.Date.ts` method is added:

```
library(xts)
> methods('as.Date')
 [1] as.Date.character as.Date.date      as.Date.dates     as.Date.default   as.Date.factor    as.Date.numeric   as.Date.POSIXct   as.Date.POSIXlt  
 [9] as.Date.ts        as.Date.yearmon   as.Date.yearqtr
```

And then it works perfect:

```
> t1 <- ts(1:20, start = c(2014, 1), frequency = 12)
> head(as.Date(time(t1)))
[1] "2014-01-01" "2014-02-01" "2014-03-01" "2014-04-01" "2014-05-01" "2014-06-01"
```

So, this is not an OS error this happened because @akrun probably had `xts` already loaded whereas the OP didn't